# Truffle tests, Type Error: it is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, truffle

I am new to testing with java script and also new to writing smart contracts. I have watched some tutorials regarding writing the tests and tried to orientate my test with for example the Metacoin example from truffle.

Now when I try to run my basic first test to get the total supply of my ERC20 token, i get the following error message:

1. Uncaught error outside test suite

0 passing (2ms)
1 failing

1. Uncaught error outside test suite:
   Uncaught TypeError: it is not a function

My test code looks like this:

```html
const { assert } = require("console");
const { it } = require("ethers/wordlists");

const charytoken = artifacts.require("CharyToken"); 

contract("CharyToken test", async accounts => {
    it("should get the Balance of CT of this contract", async() => {
        const instance = await charytoken.deployed(); 
        const ctbalance = await instance.totalSupply.call(); 
        assert.equal(ctbalance.valueOf(), 10000000000000000000000);
    }); 
});
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong/ I am missing, I would appreachiate help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you imported the wrong `it`. It's not from `ethers/wordlist`